# Illustrated short with memory-wiped man being shown down a hallway to an elevator

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, illustrated-story

I’m looking for an illustrated story that would have been from the late 70s or early 80s. Possibly published in Creepy, Eerie or maybe the Epic magazine. I’m pretty sure it was in color, but maybe that’s my memory. It was illustrated as 3 or 4 panels per Page.

It begins with a person waking and it’s from their point of view. You never see them. A person (or two) is talking to him(?) and leading him down a hallway. He’s confused, asking questions. The person(s) leading him keeps talking and somewhat answers his questions, but you get they’re being vague. Along the way though (walking through this hallway), from the dialogue, you realize he’s piecing things together from the person talking and the person is upset he’s remembering. He’s not supposed to remember as his memories were intentionally deleted or blocked.

Ultimately, he’s led into (maybe looks like) an elevator just as he remembers everything and the doors close in his face. It’s like he’s off on a space mission.

Comment: I'm confused about what makes this '*person has conversation with an amnesia sufferer*' story into science fiction or fantasy

Comment: First, I was referred to this site for my search. Second, it was like a sci if story in that it was like the person was going on a space mission and had his memory deleted for the sake of the journey (so as to not go insane?), but unfortunately remembered and then it was too late. They closed the doors and he was on his way

Comment: That's fine. I've made a small edit to indicate that this is indeed on-topic. Deleting people's memories is certainly out of the ordinary.

Comment: Thank you....!!